# How to use golang c-shared library in go

Tags: go

I wrote c-shared library using go.

```
package main

import "C"
import "log"

//export RunLib
func RunLib() {
    log.Println("Call RunLib")
}

func init() {
    log.Println("Call init")
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Call main")
}
```

I created the library using this command:
`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o lib.so lib.go`

To use the library, I wrote this golang code.

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void callFromLib() {
    void (*fn)();
    void *h = dlopen("lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!h) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }

    *(void**)(&fn) = dlsym(h, "RunLib");
    if (!fn) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(h);
        return;
    }

    fn();
    dlclose(h);
}

 */
import "C"

func main() {
    C.callFromLib()
}
```

If I run the last code it throws this error (`go run call.go`):

```
fatal error: bad sweepgen in refill

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0xb990782, 0xc000042a38})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1198 +0x71 fp=0xc000042a18 sp=0xc0000429e8 pc=0xb930691
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x41215b8, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:156 +0x24e fp=0xc000042a68 sp=0xc000042a18 pc=0xb91434e
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x41215b8, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:880 +0x85 fp=0xc000042ab0 sp=0xc000042a68 pc=0xb90ba85
runtime.mallocgc(0x8, 0xb9ba300, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1071 +0x4e8 fp=0xc000042b30 sp=0xc000042ab0 pc=0xb90c108
runtime.growslice(0xb9ba300, {0x0, 0x41a1910, 0x2}, 0xc00009c000)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:267 +0x4ea fp=0xc000042b98 sp=0xc000042b30 pc=0xb94586a
sync.(*Pool).pinSlow(0xba394e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/pool.go:223 +0x105 fp=0xc000042c30 sp=0xc000042b98 pc=0xb960ec5
sync.(*Pool).pin(0xba394e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/pool.go:206 +0x4e fp=0xc000042c48 sp=0xc000042c30 pc=0xb960d8e
sync.(*Pool).Get(0xba394e0)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/pool.go:128 +0x25 fp=0xc000042c80 sp=0xc000042c48 pc=0xb960ac5
fmt.newPrinter()
        /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:137 +0x25 fp=0xc000042ca8 sp=0xc000042c80 pc=0xb985d45
fmt.Sprintln({0xc000042d38, 0x1, 0x1})
        /usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go:280 +0x28 fp=0xc000042cf0 sp=0xc000042ca8 pc=0xb986008
log.Println({0xc000042d38, 0x24, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/log/log.go:329 +0x1e fp=0xc000042d20 sp=0xc000042cf0 pc=0xb98cd5e
main.RunLib(...)
        /Users/.../demo/lib.go:8
_cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib(0xc000042d90)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:36 +0x45 fp=0xc000042d58 sp=0xc000042d20 pc=0xb98cf85
runtime.cgocallbackg1(0xb98cf40, 0xc000042e60, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:306 +0x29a fp=0xc000042e28 sp=0xc000042d58 pc=0xb903d1a
runtime.cgocallbackg(0xc0000001a0, 0x300000002, 0xc0000001a0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:232 +0x109 fp=0xc000042eb8 sp=0xc000042e28 pc=0xb9039e9
runtime.cgocallbackg(0xb98cf40, 0x7ffeefbff737, 0x0)
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x2f fp=0xc000042ee0 sp=0xc000042eb8 pc=0xb95e32f
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.cgocallback called from 0x4053e00
stack: frame={sp:0xc000042ee0, fp:0xc000042f08} stack=[0xc000042000,0xc000043000)
0x000000c000042de0:  0x000000c000042d9d  0x000000c000042e18 
0x000000c000042df0:  0x000000000b95843b <runtime.exitsyscall+0x00000000000000fb>  0x000000c0000001a0 
0x000000c000042e00:  0x000000c000042dd8  0x0000000000000000 
0x000000c000042e10:  0x000000000b9c3dc0  0x000000c000042ea8 
0x000000c000042e20:  0x000000000b9039e9 <runtime.cgocallbackg+0x0000000000000109>  0x000000000b98cf40 <_cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib+0x0000000000000000> 
...
<_cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib+0x0000000000000000> 
0x000000c000042ea0:  0x00007ffeefbff737  0x000000c000042ed0 
0x000000c000042eb0:  0x000000000b95e32f <runtime.cgocallbackg+0x000000000000002f>  0x000000c0000001a0 
...
<runtime.cgocallback+0x00000000000000b4> 
0x000000c000042ee0: <0x000000000b98cf40 <_cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib+0x0000000000000000>  0x00007ffeefbff737 
...
runtime.cgocallback(0x4004165, 0x4058340, 0xc000042f70)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:915 +0xb4 fp=0xc000042f08 sp=0xc000042ee0 pc=0xb95c134

goroutine 1 [runnable, locked to thread]:
unicode.init()
        /usr/local/go/src/unicode/tables.go:9 +0x79
exit status 2
```

But if I use python everything works correctly!

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("lib.so")
>>> 2022/03/02 01:08:17 Call init

>>> lib.RunLib()
2022/03/02 01:08:22 Call RunLib
0
>>>
```

**Informations**

OS: macOs Big Sur 11.6.3 (20G415)

```
>>> clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
```

```
>>> nm lib.so| grep RunLib
000000000008cfa0 T _RunLib
000000000008cf40 t __cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib
00000000000c4200 s __cgoexp_6b951f94a90e_RunLib.stkobj
```

```
>>> go env
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="~/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="~/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="~/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="~/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="~/projects/go/.../go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/wl/9rtfdx8x7jvgyn6t8hpq7yh00000gn/T/go-build401121298=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I googled and found this article. But there is no golang in the article.

https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf

Comment: You cannot use a c-shared Go library in a Go program.

Comment: You have some 25-line of C-code in your _main_ code -- commented out. Is that intentional?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond it is cgo code!

Comment: @shranet I don't see the `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -llib` flag to tell the go compiler to link the shared libray while its buiilding program

Comment: @Chandan I don't need it. I want to use the library dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

A Go contributor writes that it is not possible to have two Go runtimes in one image. The comment refers to Windows, but seems to apply to macOS as well, since I can reliably reproduce the crash mentioned by the OP:

> If I am understanding correctly, you are using a Go program to open a C++ DLL and the C++ DLL opens a Go DLL. I'm sorry, this won't work on Windows. There can only be one copy of the Go runtime in the program image on Windows, but you are trying to have two.

see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50304#issuecomment-999302888

However since the OP uses macOS there is an alternative: the use of plugins, see https://pkg.go.dev/plugin:

> Package plugin implements loading and symbol resolution of Go plugins.

The command to create the library would change as follows:

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o lib.so lib.go
```

Accordingly, your call to the function defined in your library would then look something like this in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    plug, err := plugin.Open("lib.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    runLib, err := plug.Lookup("RunLib")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    runLib.(func())()
}
```

A test with this program generates the following logging outputs:

```
stephan@mac golang-c-lib-in-go % go run call.go                                 
2022/10/29 23:23:01 Call init
2022/10/29 23:23:01 Call RunLib
```

If the library is also to be used for calling from C and/or Python, then one possibility is to create the library in two variants: one that is called from C and/or Python, as shown in the question, and one in the plugin variant that can then be used by Go programs.

In your example, you don't need to make any changes in `lib.go`, the only difference is the command line to create the library.

Finally, an important note from the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin):

> Currently plugins are only supported on Linux, FreeBSD, and macOS.

Comment: from C/C++, can we link twice a "c-archive" go library? A C++ library that calls the go lib, then the app that calls the C++ can also call the go library.

Answer (score 3):

The problem described by the original poster looks weird. I could not reproduce it on Linux.

My setup: Ubuntu 18, Go 1.19.2, gcc 7.5.0

I made only one change: added pragma `#cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl` to the `C` snippet. It is required by GCC to enable `dlopen & Co`.

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void callFromLib() {
    void (*fn)();
    void *h = dlopen("lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!h) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return;
    }

    *(void**)(&fn) = dlsym(h, "RunLib");
    if (!fn) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(h);
        return;
    }

    fn();
    dlclose(h);
}

*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.callFromLib()
}
```

Launched as:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/tmp/try-go/ go run call.go
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable points to the directory with `lib.so`

Output:

```
2022/10/26 09:39:10 Call init
2022/10/26 09:39:10 Call RunLib
```

As expected, no errors.

The original error `bad sweepgen in refill` is raised by the garbage collector. The cache of objects became incoherent. I suspect the issue is that there are two runtimes and two garbage collectors in the program - one comes from the calling program and the other is from the loaded `lib.so`. It looks like two garbage collectors clashed while running over the same heap.

Anyway, in go 1.19 the code works. Still I wouldn't load Go shared object through C `dlopen` - who knows how two Go runtimes could interact, especially if they are from different compilers versions.

Comment: Out of curiosity @pak-uula, did you try running this multiple times? I have a scenario (under macOS, so no need to include `-ldl`) where the first time I tested, I had no errors, but each subsequent time, I do.

Comment: @msbit `for i in $(seq 1 100); do LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../try-go-lib ./call.exe ; done` worked fine on Linux. Here `call.exe` is the binary built by go `go build -o call.exe call.go`

Comment: I'd say conclusive, then :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this [blog](https://github.com/lxwagn/using-go-with-c-libraries) which discusses linking go programs with c libraries in detail.

Your code in the go program seems to be missing the compiler and linker instructions:

#cgo CFLAGS: -I./src

#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./lib -lmylib -Wl,-rpath=./lib

Comment: While likely well-intentioned, this isn't right as [`dlopen`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dlopen&sektion=3&format=html) operates at runtime, without requiring the library to be referred to at link time ✌

Comment: You are proposing that the c code dynamically during run time would have to find dlopen and link to it. That process would require a c runtime environment operating on top of or in conjunction with the go run time library.  I dont believe that the go run time library can search during runtime dynamically for c routines that might be called on by the cgo routine. It makes more sense that the compiler identifies dlopen as a routine that needs to be linked to and the linker identifies the c library entry point in the linking process (or if it cannot find the shared library flags an error)

Comment: No, I am not. I'm noting that `dlopen` is a function that operates at runtime, loading the provided object file into the process, and that this does not require that object file to be named during compilation or linking (for example using the `LDFLAGS` you'd provided).